# Is the gnome compositing manager decent for Steam VR?

Tags: graphics, steam, 18.10

I have a Hades Canyon NUC with a AMD Vega M GPU, and it *seems* to be powerful enough for VR - the mirroring view is almost flawless - but on the headset itself the view is jumpy when moving around.
It'll display the move correctly, but then a frame will be displayed with the previous position, before it settles back on the correct position. Framebuffer issues right? (Tracking is perfect in the mirror view)

There's a whole lot of stuff about ["allow applications to block compositing"](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9g3nts/certain_games_doesnt_block_compositing_how_to/) but that seems to apply to KDE, and standard Ubuntu 18.10 (Gnome 3?) turns off compositing "automatically"

As far as I know, I've installed vulkan properly and windows games do run (proton/steam play).

**What compositor should I be using to get the best results with SteamVR?**

**Related questions** that I can think of or arise while performing the answer to the main question (let's make this easier for people with the same problem as mine):

- Does my desktop need to be the same "flavour" as the compositor? (Ubuntu -> Gnome, KDE to KWin etc)
- What settings should I set (or be looking at in general) for the chosen compositor?

**Other notes**
When Ubuntu boots, the login screen is shown in the vive. After login, the vive deactivates and the main window is as normal.
Entering and exiting VR makes the desktop window "alter" a bit before resettling - just like when a new monitor is plugged in. (Is this normal?)

Comment: Actually, I should open an issue over at https://github.com/ValveSoftware/SteamVR-for-Linux/blob/master/issue_template.md

Comment: I've created https://github.com/ValveSoftware/SteamVR-for-Linux/issues/219, because this should "just work" right?

Comment: I've been running into the exact same problems, the mirroring view runs very smooth, but the performance on the HMD display leaves something to be desired.  My suspicion is that gnome is still compositing the mirror view (since that's not fullscreen, and therefore would *not* bypass mutter).  I'd be curious to try Steam VR on an XFCE setup where you can explicitly disable displaying compositing for XFWM4.  See this post about how to do that when launching a game.  https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensiveLinux/comments/6b3cs5/is_it_possible_to_disable_compositing_in_xfce_for/